# How to Dynamically create checkboxes in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, react-hooks

```
function Screen() {
 const [lvls, setLvls] = React.useState([]);
  const [done, setDone] = React.useState(null);
  const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => { 
    async function checkData() {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        setLvls(data);
    }
    checkData();
    setDone(true);
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
          {done && (lvls.length) ? (
                  lvls.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                    <View key={i} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>

                      <CheckBox
                        disabled={false}
                        value={toggleCheckBox}
                        onValueChange={(newValue) => setToggleCheckBox(newValue)}
                      />

                      <Text style={styles.text}>{lvls[i]}</Text>

                    </View>)
                  })
                  ):
                (
                  <Text style={styles.emptyText}>NO</Text>
          )}
      </View>
    );
}
```

My aim is to dynamically render a checkbox that corresponds to each element in `lvls`.
I am currently doing that, however all of the checkboxes share the same state `toggleCheckbox`.
How can I create unique states for each checkbox according to lvls?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `object` that will store all the checkboxes values.

```js
const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = React.useState({})

                      <CheckBox
                        disabled={false}
                        value={toggleCheckBox[i] ? true : false}
                        onValueChange={() => 
                          setToggleCheckBox({
                            ...toggleCheckBox,
                            [i] : !toggleCheckBox[i]
                            })}
                      />
```

Placing into your code...

```js
function Screen() {
 const [lvls, setLvls] = React.useState([]);
  const [done, setDone] = React.useState(null);
  const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = React.useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => { 
    async function checkData() {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        setLvls(data);
    }
    checkData();
    setDone(true);
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
          {done && (lvls.length) ? (
                  lvls.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                    <View key={i} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>

                      <CheckBox
                        disabled={false}
                        value={toggleCheckBox[i] ? true : false}
                        onValueChange={() => 
                          setToggleCheckBox({
                            ...toggleCheckBox,
                            [i] : !toggleCheckBox[i]
                            })}
                      />

                      <Text style={styles.text}>{lvls[i]}</Text>

                    </View>)
                  })
                  ):
                (
                  <Text style={styles.emptyText}>NO</Text>
          )}
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Interesting, are the checkbox states (togglecheckbox[i]) being initialized on the spot?

Comment: It begins a empty object, so all values will return undefined. When execute the onValueChange the !undefined returns true. When is already true and execute onValueChange, will return false.